# What does a method GetActivity with parameter quotaUser do in Google+?

Tags: parameters, google-api, google-plus

In Google + there is a method GetActivity, it has a parameter quotaUser. What does this parameter do?
[docs link](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get)

[image: image with problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quotaUser` (and `userIp`) are values you can provide the API when making requests from server-side code. The values of `quotaUser` and `userIp` will bucket API usage by their values to prevent requests taken on behalf of a single user maxing your your available rate limits.

For example if user `cat` tells your server to make 10,000 requests (because cats are greedy), once they hit the limit per user they can't make any more requests. The `dog` user can continue making requests however because your application as a whole is still under the total rate limit.

It's not required/used for all APIs. It's configurable in some cases. It's handled automatically when requests are coming from user's devices or authenticated by user access tokens instead of application keys.

[Capping API usage](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7035610)